# Qt on Android - does the C++ code run in the Dalvik virtual machine

Tags: android, c++, qt

I have heard it said that the C++ code runs "natively" on all platforms.  By this I guess that what is being suggested is that the cross-platform ability of Qt is not using something like HTML 5.

But does this mean that on Android Qt code runs in the Dalvik virtual machine?

Comment: It requires NDK to run

Comment: Dalvik is for Java code, native code is executed natively, it just "hooks" to android via the Java wrappers through Dalvik.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android understands either Dalvik or the newer ART. Dalvik and ART both have the ability to link to C/C++ code through the Android NDK which is Android's take on JNI. QT for Android while being C++ based still requires [a minimal amount of Java](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html) based initialization. What this means is that even if the C++ code runs ***natively*** (architecture dependent) to the underlying OS, it is still required to be presented through code that runs on the VM (Android specific) as the VM does not directly understand C++ but can link to it through it's own Java based framework which is the Android NDK.

Answer (score 3):

Please check https://www.qt.io/blog/2013/07/23/anatomy-of-a-qt-5-for-android-application

At the very top of levels, a Qt for Android application consists of two parts:

The Qt application:
This is the cross-platform code and resources that you, as the app developer, manage yourself, and which are summarized by your qmake .pro file.

An Android application launcher:
This is generated for you by Qt Creator the first time you connect your project to a Qt for Android Kit.

So, Android application launcher should run in Dalvik VM. I can't sure if this works well with [ART runtime](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/art.html) of Android 5.0